# Django URL patterns contain trailing whitespace

Tags: django, django-urls

Django authentication views are being included as

```
admin/
accounts/ login/ [name='login']
accounts/ logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/ password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/ password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/ password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/ password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/ reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/ reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

rather then

```
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']
```

My URL dispatcher automatically includes 1 whitespace to any part of the URL that gets added, even after parsing the one trailing `accounts`. Want to know if there is a way to stop this from happening entirely without having to parse my URLs on my own.
My urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(s'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')))
]
```

Comment: The whitespace is not part of the URL. This is just to make the includes visible.

Comment: I set up views to the url without a whitespace and the url coudln't be found.

Comment: Exactly *what* URL are you visiting?

Comment: This was all in a previous project mind you, but I had a view and url all set up to go to (host)/accounts/login/

Comment: django shouldn't add spaces - maybe somewhere you have it with space at the end `"accounts/ "`. Maybe if you use `searching in file` (in your editor/IDE) with `"accounts/ "` then you find it.

Comment: Can you show the full error message including the part that says what path was not matched?